# Change XML grandchild value if child value is equal to another value

Tags: python, xml, parsing, element, elementtree

I need to correct a few hundred of XML files.

Let's say files are of this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyData xmlns="urn:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso">
  <Hdr>
    <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso">
      <St>A</St>
      <To>Z</To>
  </Hdr>
  <Data>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso">
      <CountryReport>
        <RptHdr>
            <RpDtls>
                <Dt>2018-07-10</Dt>
          </RpDtls>
        </RptHdr>
        <Country>
          <Id>PT</Id>
          <FullNm>Portugal</FullNm>>
          <Bd>
            <Tp>US</Tp>
          </Bd>
        </Country>
        <Country>
          <Id>ESP</Id>
          <FullNm>Spain</FullNm>>
          <Bd>
            <Tp>EUR</Tp>
          </Bd>
        </Country>
      </CountryReport>
    </Document>
  </Data>
</MyData>
```

The replacement I need to do is the following:

- If the Country ID is PT, I need to replace the Bd/Tp to "EUR".

I've try different ways using sed, xmllint and ElementTrees using python but without success.

I may be using the wrong xpath but I unfortunately cannot figure it out.

Can you help?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Perhaps try posting what you've tried and where you suspect to have had a "wrong xpath". People are generally much more happy to help when they see the effort that went into it so far and can help tackle a specific problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve your goal would be using an XSLT-processor. For example, use a script that calls the Linux program [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) or the Windows/Linux program [`saxon`](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Because your elements are in a namespace, you have to define it for your elements. For example, add `xmlns:ui="urn:iso"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` element and then use the following template in combination with the *identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="ui:Country[ui:Id='PT']/ui:Bd/ui:Tp">
  <xsl:element name="Tp" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">EUR</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The *identity template* of XSLT-1.0 is:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT-3.0 you could use the following instruction instead:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```

So a complete XSLT-1.0 file to transform all of your XML files could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ui="urn:iso">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="ui:Country[ui:Id='PT']/ui:Bd/ui:Tp">
    <xsl:element name="Tp" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">EUR</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An `xsltproc` bash command could look like

```
for file in *; do xsltproc transform.xslt $file > $file.NEW; done;
```

Comment: Or you could run XSLT 1.0 with Python's [lxml library](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt).